# How do I effectively store or retrieve messages in a Firestore Chat app without this problem?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is this instead of adding new data, the existing data in the Firestore Database gets updated. This leads to the display of the last message that is either sent or received in the ChatActivity. Also the message I send appears twice on the screen after sending but once I leave the activity and open it again as i just stated, only the last message that is either sent or received in the ChatActivity is displayed. After a lot of scouring on the internet, and testing out various alternatives on my own and failing to resolve this issue, I now come to this community for help.

I have posted below the methods I am using to send my message from the app to the database and the method to then display those messages.

send message method

```
private void sendMessage(String sender,String receiver,String message){
        DocumentReference documentReference = rootRef.collection("chats").document(roomId).collection("messages").document(roomId);
        Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("sender",sender);
        user.put("receiver",receiver);
        user.put("message",message);
        user.put("time", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
        user.put("rid",roomId);
        documentReference.set(user,SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: MessageSent "+ userId);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Error"+ userId);
            }
        });
    }
```

get message method

```
private void readMessages(final String userId, final String recipientId){
    mchat = new ArrayList<>();
    CollectionReference collectionReference = rootRef.collection("chats").document(roomId).collection("messages");
    collectionReference.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
    collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onEvent: Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }
            if(documentSnapshots!=null){
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots : documentSnapshots){
                    Chat chat = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObject(Chat.class);
                    if(chat.getReceiver().equals(recipientId)&&chat.getSender().equals(userId)||
                    chat.getReceiver().equals(userId)&&chat.getSender().equals(recipientId)){
                        mchat.add(chat);
                    }
                    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mchat);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're attaching your listener with `addSnapshotListener`, your `onEvent` method will get called once when you attach the listener and then each time the data it listens to gets modified. So when a message is added, your `onEvent` gets called again.

Each time the `onEvent` runs, you read all messages from the database and add them to your view. So the first time that is correct, as you add all initial messages. But on the subsequent calls, you're re-adding the same messages that you already processed over and over.

You have two main options to solve this:

1. Wipe the existing messages before processing
2. Handle only the updates

**Wiping the existing messages** is the simplest, as all you have to do is clear `` at the start of `onEvent`:

```
private void readMessages(final String userId, final String recipientId){
    mchat = new ArrayList<>();
    CollectionReference collectionReference = rootRef.collection("chats").document(roomId).collection("messages");
    collectionReference.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onEvent: Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }
            mChat.clear();
            if(documentSnapshots!=null){
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots : documentSnapshots){
                    Chat chat = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObject(Chat.class);
                    if(chat.getReceiver().equals(recipientId)&&chat.getSender().equals(userId)||
                    chat.getReceiver().equals(userId)&&chat.getSender().equals(recipientId)){
                        mchat.add(chat);
                    }
                    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mchat);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I also changed where the `.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)` call is. Each call to `orderBy` (and most other query building methods) returns a new object, so you have to chain the calls.

---

**Handling only updates** is a bit more involved, but will be more efficient. This means that when you have a lot of documents, it has less chances of flicker in your UI.

I highly recommend reading [handling changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) in the documentation. For the most simple case where you only add new documents to the collection, you could get by with:

```
private void readMessages(final String userId, final String recipientId){
    mchat = new ArrayList<>();
    CollectionReference collectionReference = rootRef.collection("chats").document(roomId).collection("messages");
    collectionReference.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onEvent: Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }
            mChat.clear();
            if(documentSnapshots!=null){
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){ // first change is here

                    switch (dc.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:
                            Chat chat = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObject(Chat.class);
                            if(chat.getReceiver().equals(recipientId)&&chat.getSender().equals(userId)||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(userId)&&chat.getSender().equals(recipientId)){
                                mchat.add(chat);
                            }
                            break;
                        case MODIFIED:
                            Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                            break;
                        case REMOVED:
                            Log.d(TAG, "Removed city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                            break;
                    }

                    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mchat);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For a more complete solution, you'll want to:

1. Handle the `MODIFIED` and `REMOVED` events too, by updating and removing the existing messages in/from `mchat`.
2. Only call `new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mchat)` once, and on subsequent updates call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` to tell it of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the new messages are overriding the old messages because of this line:

```
DocumentReference documentReference = rootRef.collection("chats").document(roomId).collection("messages").document(roomId);
```

I believe you need to make the last .document() call have something other than roomId for the value because if the roomId stays the same then you will never be able to have more than one message in the same messages collection. Maybe change the roomId to messageId.

For reading problem see @Frank van Puffelen answer